# How to append an element before another using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I tried following the a wiki and looking into multiple questions here but I still have problems with insertBefore..

This is my sample:

```
<div id="container">
 <span id="first">1</span>
 <span id="second">2</span>
 <div id="third">3</div>
 <div id="forth">4</div>
</div>

<script>
topbar = document.getElementsById("container");
boardlist = document.getElementsById("first");

bmcontainer = document.createElement("span");
bmcontainer.setAttribute("id", "zero");
bmcontainer.innerHTML("0");

topbar.inserBefore(bmcontainer, boardlist);
</script>
```

I want to append the span#zero before the span#first. What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to not use jQuery, so I'm looking for a totally javascript solution.

Comment: I think you have a typo.. `topbar.inserBefore` instead of `topbar.insertBefore`

Comment: You have another typo `getElementsById` should be `getElementById`

Comment: `.innerHTML` is a property, not a method. You need `.innerHTML = "0"`, plus fix the typos already mentioned, and then your code will work. I'm voting to close this as typo-based.

Comment: `browser's dev console`, `browser's dev console` and `browser's dev console`

Comment: oh! I'm sorry for all the typos I made, I started learning js yesterday and I still write everything on notepad instead of using a proper editor. correcting all the typos and the innerHTML error solved the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) is the answer.

```
var insertedNode = parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode);
```

If you have `Parent Node`, then you should use [`ParentNode.prepend()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend)

```
ParentNode.prepend(nodesToPrepend);
```

Take a look @ mentioned links for full documentation and examples.

**Update**

You have some issues in your code (*typo and wrong usage of `innerHTML`*), here is fixed code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <span id="first">1</span>
    <span id="second">2</span>
    <div id="third">3</div>
    <div id="forth">4</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var topbar = document.getElementById("container"),
    boardlist = document.getElementById("first"),
    bmcontainer = document.createElement("span");

bmcontainer.setAttribute("id", "zero");   
bmcontainer.innerHTML = "0"; // innerHTML is not a function, it's a property

topbar.insertBefore(bmcontainer, boardlist);
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mdehghani/4fog9emv/)

Notice that `InnerHTML` **is not** a `function`, it's a `property`, read more about that here: [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Comment: *"Node.insertBefore() is the answer."* - The OP is already trying to use that method without success.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the insertAdjacentElement function.

```
var boardlist = document.getElementById("first"),
    bmcontainer = document.createElement("span");
    bmcontainer.setAttribute("id", "zero");

    boardlist.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', bmcontainer);
```

[Element.insertAdjacentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)

Comment: thanks for this alternative method! you too have a typo in the first part (getElementS.. instead of getElement..)

Answer (score 0):

**Prepend pure javascript**

[MDN article on insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

```
var el = document.getElementById('thingy'),
    elChild = document.createElement('div');
elChild.innerHTML = 'Content';

// Prepend it
el.insertBefore(elChild, el.firstChild);
```

Source: http://clubmate.fi/append-and-prepend-elements-with-pure-javascript/#Prepend

**Also, the jQuery prepend() Method**

You can read about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_prepend.asp).

Comment: *"For prepending insertBefore() method needs to be used"* - Yes, and the OP know that: the question mentions it. So what's wrong with *their* code?